# Linq include only max row

Tags: c#, linq

I'm pulling items from a table that i'm including another table.
When including, there is likely multiple rows belonging to that item in the included table but I only want to include the row that contains the max value of a column.

```
items.AddRange(db.AuctionItems
    .Include(f => f.AuctionBids.Max().Bid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item));
```

Also tried

```
items.AddRange(db.AuctionItems
    .Include(f => f.AuctionBids.Max(y => y.Bid))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item));
```

Error

`The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.`

***Added info***

Table AuctionItems

```
ID
Name
.....
```

Table AuctionBids

```
ID
ItemID
Bid
....
```

So I want to pull all items and include only the row that contains the highest bid for that item.

Comment: `When including, there is likely multiple rows belonging to that item in the included table but I only want to include the row that contains the max value of a column.` Can you give some examples of what would be in these tables and what you'd want to extract out of it? Your description is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry I have added some extra info. Hope I help clear up the confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504006/get-subset-of-entity-navigation-properties

Comment: @Digifaktur I don't see how that is a duplicate as it doesn't answer my question and the original question is different. I know how to include but I only want to include the row that contains the max value for that item it relates to.

Comment: @Tsukasa exactly. the first sentence of the topmost answer is: "You can't filter or affect in some other way data which are loaded into navigation properties." Which is exactly what you are trying to do - filter your navigation property `AuctionBid` by maximum.

Comment: @Digifaktur so what is the proper way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
db.AuctionItems
  .Select(s => new{ai = s, bid = s.AuctionBids.OrderByDescending(o => o.Bid).FirstOrDefault()})
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(s => s.ai)
```

Using this approach you are loading only required `AuctionBid`s into context and EF will do the mapping to appropriate `AuctionItem`s for you.

Comment: Can you explain ai = a? it doesn't like the value a.

Comment: @Tsukasa, oh sorry, I misspelled. it is `s`, not `a`

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be a way to do this. Maybe I didn't ask in the correct way.